# Is there a Cardano VM?

Tags: cardano-node

Does Cardano have a virtual machine? Throughout crypto we hear a lot about EVM but have never heard any reference to a Cardano VM? Is there a need for a VM for Cardano or has the system been architected in away that eliminates the need?

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum, Solana, and other blockchains that use an accounts-based ledger model can each be thought of as one big box of logical interdependencies, whose *state* is constantly changing, all replicated, maintained, and updated by many nodes. Keeping track of and executing all these interdependencies requires a "VM" - a sort of universe in which all these logical structures can live in context with one another. This allows for a high degree of flexibility and customizability, but also makes it difficult to model and prevent chaotic side effects.

Bitcoin, Cardano, and other blockchains that use a UTXO-based ledger model are different. Instead of thinking of the blockchain as one big box (as in the previous case), it is better to think of it as a collection, or a *set*, of many little boxes (a.k.a UTXOs). The whole UTXO set is replicated and constantly changing like any other blockchain, but **there are no interdependencies between the UTXOs themselves.** Instead, each UTXO contains just enough information it needs to only ever be spent *exactly* how the creator of the UTXO intended it. There is no notion of a shared "global state", and hence no need for a VM.

Comment: The "VM" aspect is not dependent on how state is managed or what transaction record models are implemented in a given blockchain stack (that's a bonus), but rather the approaches by which execution code is equipped to interface with hardware platforms. Case in point: Fuel uses the Fuel VM with a UTXO transaction recording model.

Languages like C and Haskell are able to interface well with native machines due to maturity in builds/compilers/libraries whereas Java for example requires the JRE (JVM + other components) as helpers to function, or in this case Solidity with the EVM.

Answer (score 0):

My answer as shared under your twitter comment [here](https://twitter.com/thepizzaknight_/status/1550332974524145665?s=20&t=wqYk7V1LmFi5f5VVv-Jzkg)

It's not necessary, Plutus is a subset of Haskell which has a mature library i.e. GHC (runtime env, toolchains, etc) and is able compile instructions directly to machine code.

It can still utilise one like WASM/LLVM for various needs.

TL;DR: The Cardano Node is the machine.

Comment: Plutus is not compiled directly to machine code, but to a defined language called Plutus Core. Plutus Core is an eagerly-evaluated version of the untyped lambda calculus extended with some “built-in” types and functions; it is intended for the implementation of validation scripts on the Cardano blockchain (from the plutus-core-specification document)